# How to fix my 'delete' button angular [routerLink] error

Tags: angular, mean-stack, ngfor, angular-routerlink

I recently added a simple delete button to my `homepage.html` using:

```
<button style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.226); background- 
color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; 
margin: 5px;"
(click)="removeCat(cat._id)">Delete</button>
```

I am getting the console error:

> HomePageComponent.html:96 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object
>   Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

I'm being told this is on line 96 of my html, this is that line

```
<tr *ngFor="let cat of cats">
<td>{{cat.breedname}}</td>
<td>{{cat.age}}</td>
<td>{{cat.gender}}</td>
<td>{{cat.comfortablecatdog}}</td>
<td>{{cat.comfortablekids}}</td>
<td>{{cat.health}}</td>
<button
  style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(0, 164, 240, 0.267); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
      [routerLink]="['/cats', cat._id]">Details</button>
    <button
      style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 217, 0, 0.267); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
      [routerLink]="['/cats', cat._id, 'edit']">Edit</button>
    <button style="border: 1.5px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.226); background-color: whitesmoke; border-radius: 23px; font-size: 15px; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;"
    (click)="removeCat(cat._id)">Delete</button>
  </tr>
```

This is my `homepage.ts`:

```
removeCat(_id) {
var tempObeservable = this._httpService.removeCatById(_id);
tempObeservable.subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log('got a response from delete');
  var tempObeservable = this._httpService.getAllPets();
  tempObeservable.subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log('got a response from ngoninit', data);
    this.cats = data;
  })
})
```

}

This is my http.service.ts

```
    removeCatById(_id){
    console.log('deleteDog', _id);
    return this._http.delete(`/api/pets/${_id}/deletecat`, _id);
  }
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts

```
    {path: 'cats/:id/deletecat', component: HomePageComponent},
```

This is my routers.js

```
      app.delete('/api/pets/:id/deletecat', pets.deleteCat);
```

And this is my pets.js controller

```
      deleteCat: (req, res) => {
        Cat.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("hit delete but got errors", err);
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'succesfully deleted' });
            }
        })
    }
```

My other buttons work fine, the 'edit' and 'details', however those are using [routerLink]'s instead of my (click) function. None of the answers I found online seemed to have helped. I'd be happy to provide more code if I didn't supply enough.

Thank you.

[edit]
I should mention the button will still delete the proper object but only display after I refresh the page.

Comment: The error means that the *ngFor can't work because you're trying to iterate over an object instead of iterating ver an array. I.e. `cats` is not an array.

Comment: @JBNizet this is my homepagecomponent.ts where the cats array should be coming from `export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  newCat: any;
  newDog: any;
  cats = [];
  dogs = [];` Am I supposed to be specifying which cat instead of 'any' or the '[]' brackets?

Comment: No. You're supposed to debug and see what is actually returned instead of an array by the HTTP service you're using to get the cats.